# Can't get views by insightTrafficSourceType — YouTube Analytics API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube-api, analytics

So I'm using the 'google-api-client' gem with Rails, and I'm attempting to call the URL below in order to get video views by `day` and `insightTrafficSourceType`. This is a call that appears to be allowable from the [Available Reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports%20Available%20Reports) documentation page.

Additionally, I found that I was able to make this call by using the API Explorer tool provided by Google.

URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1beta1/reports?metrics=views&ids=channel==CHANNEL_ID&dimensions=day,insightTrafficSourceType&filter=video==VIDEO_ID&start-date=2013-01-15&end-date=2013-01-16&start-time=1970-01-01

Result:

```
{
  :error=>
    {
      "errors"=>[
        {
          "domain"=>"global",
          "reason"=>"invalid",
          "message"=>"Unknown identifier (insightTrafficSourceType) given in field parameters.dimensions."
        }
      ],
      "code"=>400,
      "message"=>"Unknown identifier (insightTrafficSourceType) given in field parameters.dimensions."
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what extra data I can provide in the initial description of this bug, but as stated before I am making the call to the API with the Google::APIClient Ruby library. The actual code itself looks like this:

```
client.execute(
  :api_method => api.reports.query,
  :parameters => options
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are still referencing the old beta API, i.e., in your URL, you have 'v1beta' and you should have 'v1' there.  Try replacing that and running it again.  Also, you can look at the api explorer to see the exact URL that should be generated in live examples with your acct (once you enable OAuth) here: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/
(Look at the bottom of the page.)

Finally, start-time isn't a parameter listed on the production version of the API, so you will want to remove that as well.